# when doing a extract to interface, why doesn't it modify the interface previously created?

Tags: interface, resharper

I created an interface in a file, then a class that implements the interface in another file.

If i add a property to the implementation class, is it possible to pass that method signature down to the interface automatically using resharper?

I tried, and it seemed to just create another interface in the same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Pull Members Up refactoring - that does exactly what you need